# How to run automatically intellij background indexing

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

Is there a way to automatically generate an index without switching to the active window?

After executing ant or gradle on the command line, an index is generated,
It will not be generated unless I switch intellj to the active window.

It usually takes around 5-10 minutes to generate the index, so I have to wait too long time.
I am glad that there is a way to automatically generate it when the ant build command ends.

Comment: Do you build on the local drive? IntelliJ IDEA should be able to recognize the external changes via the native file watcher (receives notifications about file changes from the OS) and start indexing immediately.

Comment: Certainly I am running in my local folder. Therefore, the file watcher will work. However, indexing will not start unless I click on intellij.